# Game Center Turn Timeout for Multiplayer GAmes

Tags: swift, game-center, multiplayer

I have created a turn based multiplayer board game using Swift and Game Center that works pretty well. One of the last items I would like to add is a way to keep a player from abandoning a game near the end if they know they are going to lose. It seems like the turnTimeout portion of the endTurn function is built in especially for this purpose, but I cannot get it to work. My endTurn function is below:

```
func endTurn(_ model: GameModel, completion: @escaping CompletionBlock) {
    guard let match = currentMatch else {
        completion(GameCenterHelperError.matchNotFound)
        return
    }
    
    do {
        let currenParticipantIndex: Int = (match.participants.firstIndex(of: match.currentParticipant!))!
        let nextPerson = [match.participants[(currenParticipantIndex+1) % match.participants.count]]
        
        print("end turn, next participant \(String(describing: nextPerson[0].player?.alias))")
        match.endTurn(
            withNextParticipants: nextPerson,
            turnTimeout: 15,
            match: try JSONEncoder().encode(model),
            completionHandler: completion
        )
    } catch {completion(error)}
}
```

This function takes into account the advice from Anton in the comment of the answer to this question:
[Trying to set a time limit on my Game Center game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471584/trying-to-set-a-time-limit-on-my-game-center-game)
to update the array of nextParticipant players so that the end of the array is never reached. I've also tried to account for this in my testing by having both player 1 and player 2 delay the end of their turn to see if it would fire (The game is a 2 player game only)

This should also answer this question:
[Game Center turn timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506490/game-center-turn-timeouts)

The documentation says:

timeoutDate: The time at which the player must act before forfeiting a turn. Your game decides what happens when a turn is forfeited. For some games, a forfeited turn might end the match. For other games, you might choose a reasonable set of default actions for the player, or simply do nothing.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch.html

Unfortunately I am unable to get the turnTimeout function to fire at all. I have done a fair amount of research and I found no definitive answer to what function is actually called when it fires (i.e. the player takes longer than the allotted time to take their turn). I would expect that the same function is called for a timeout as a regular call of the endTurn function and the below player listener is called:

```
func player(_ player: GKPlayer, receivedTurnEventFor match: GKTurnBasedMatch, didBecomeActive: Bool) {
    if let vc = currentMatchmakerVC {
        currentMatchmakerVC = nil
        vc.dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    print("received turn event")
    if !didBecomeActive {
        print("\n\n\n player listener did become active")
        print("match did change")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .matchDidChange, object: match)
    } else if didBecomeActive {
        print("present game")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .presentGame, object: match)
    }
}
```

I am able to get the player listener (received turn event) to fire when endTurn is specifically called from the game, but I do not see anything that is called when the turnTimeout event triggers. If it was the player listener I would see the print statements in the console as well as the notification on the next player's device.

The GKTurnTimeoutDefault is 604,800 and is a Time Interval which I did some research on and arrived at the conclusion that it is in seconds, which is 7 days. I changed it to 0.00001, 15, 2000 and a few values in between but I wasn't able to get it to fire.

I also found the below, but the first has no answer and the second only says the turn timeouts probably warrants its own full answer:

[Game Center Turnbased Game turn timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692233/game-center-turnbased-game-turn-timeout)

[How to detect when Game Center turn based match has ended in iOS9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227459/how-to-detect-when-game-center-turn-based-match-has-ended-in-ios9)

I am thinking that my mistake is probably that I am unable to find the function that is called when the turn timeout fires, although I might be mistaken on the Time Interval values that I'm putting in there as well.

Thank you for taking the time to review my question :)